# Add Windows 10 Media Feature Pack using powershell

Tags: powershell

So if I look for the object, I get a result:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -online | Where-Object -Property name -eq "Media.WindowsMediaPlayer~~~~0.0.12.0"


Name  : Media.WindowsMediaPlayer~~~~0.0.12.0
State : NotPresent
```

If I try the following commands:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -online | Where-Object -Property name -eq "Media.WindowsMediaPlayer~~~~0.0.12.0" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online

Get-WindowsCapability -online | Where-Object -Property name -like "*Media*" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

I get:

```
Add-WindowsCapability : Element not found.
At line:1 char:106
+ ... Media.WindowsMediaPlayer~~~~0.0.12.0" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

And if I try:

```
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Media.WindowsMediaPlayer~~~~0.0.12.0
```

I get:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.746

Image Version: 10.0.19042.804


[==========================100.0%==========================] 

Error: 1168

Element not found.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Not sure what is going on here, the command finds the package, but then also at the same time cannot find it.   What can I try from this point?

Comment: Try `install-windowsfeature` but, ensure its there first with `Get-WindowsFeature`.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate, but 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: what powershell version are you running?